# Turning <canvas> frames into a video?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-video, html5-animation

Is there a way, either through the HTML5 canvas/video APIs or a JavaScript library to take canvas images (exported through canvas.toDataURL or something similar) and stitch them together to make a video in the browser?

Comment: If you were (very) adventurous, you could use the Typed Array API and implement a video file format... I don't think that has been done yet, though.

Comment: Hrm that may be true, but it'd probably be very computationally expensive... would a WebWorker be enough to make sure performance is stable?

Comment: ...perhaps. The AVI File format ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms779636.aspx ) would be the easiest to implement, but the biggest requirement would be memory, not speed. Mind you, it would help to offload to a Worker, especially at high frame rates.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are talking about a slideshow, but fast enough to look animated, sort of like a flipbook. I'm sure you could do this, but I think it would be better to make a movie in another app and embed that into an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

The excellent [New Zealand Tourism](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/08/behind-scenes-tourism-new-zealand/) site is doing something similar to what you describe. It was recently written up in Smashing Magazine.

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're after, but you might at least glean some inspiration here.